# UnicodeDecodeError with nltk

Tags: python, nltk, python-unicode

I am working with python2.7 and nltk on a large txt file of content **scraped** from various websites..however I am getting various unicode errors such as

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My question is not so much how I can 'fix' this with python but instead is there anything I can do to the .txt file (as in formatting) before 'feeding' it to python, such as 'make plain text' to avoid this issue entirely?

Update:

I looked around and found a solution within python that seems to work perfectly:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to open the file, and possibly the part of the file which includes the problem byte?

Comment: Hey @AlexanderCécile, thanks for your response...I was trying to fix the problem outside of python (as in format txt file) but have just found a solution that works...will up OP now

Comment: Okay, I’m glad it worked out. It still might be useful to share at least part of your code, though.

Answer (score 1):

try opening the file with:

```py
f = open(fname, encoding="ascii", errors="surrogateescape")
```

Change the "ascii" with the desired encoding.